# Is there a name for this "opposite of a projection" function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I was wondering if there is a name of a function like

$$(x_1, x_2,..., x_n) \mapsto (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n, 0, 0, ..., 0)\,.$$

I know when we do it the other way around it's called the projection. And when there is no $0$'s it's called the identity map. Is there a special name for this one?

Comment: "natural injection", perhaps.

Comment: "obvious embedding"?

Comment: "natural embedding".  Other permutations work too.

Comment: I've always heard it referred to as the inclusion map. This term can be used whenever we are identifying some object as a subspace of a "larger" one.

Comment: Thanks guys! I reckon "inclusion map" is the one I was looking for(kind of forgot the term after years). The way I present it probably confused people. And that's probably the reason that you guys gave many different answers.

Comment: [Coprojection](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coprojection)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've usually seen maps like this referred to as "the inclusion map". It is often used whenever we identify some object as a subspace of a larger one.

Maps of this kind are injective and linear, so give a well defined injective linear map (or more generally, a homomorphism of modules). If we have such an inclusion $f:U\rightarrow V$ where $U$ and $V$ are groups (or vector spaces, or $R$ modules) then by the isomorphism theorem of your choice, we have $U \cong f(U)$ as groups (or vector spaces, or $R$ modules) which is exactly what we would expect, and just agrees with the fact that we expect the original object $U$ to be somehow embedded in the larger one $V$.

Comment: @Evariste No problem, happy to help!